# $p(T) = 0$ with $\deg p \le n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V = n$, and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. I need to prove that there is a non-zero polynomial $p(x)$ of degree no more than $n^2$ such that $p(T) = 0$.

Any help or hints would be splendid.

Comment: Observe that the space $\mathcal{L}(V)$ has dimension $n^2$. Then, the elements $I$, $T$, $T^2$,...$T^{n^2}$ are necessarily linearly dependent. From this it is easy to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result is more elementary than Cayley-Hamilton, and it is not required for the proof.

Note that

$\dim \mathscr L(V) = n^2;  \tag 1$

note further that the set

$\mathscr S = \{T^k, \; 0 \le k \le n^2 \} \tag 2$

satisfies

$\vert \mathscr S \vert = n^2 + 1; \tag 2$

thus a linear dependence must hold amongst the elements of $\mathscr S$, that is, there exist $n^2 + 1$ scalars $p_0, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{n^2}$, not all zero, such that

$\displaystyle \sum_0^{n^2} p_iT^i = 0; \tag 3$

$T$ then satisfies the polynomial

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{n^2} p_i x^i, \tag 4$

and

$\deg p(x) \le n^2. \tag 5$

$OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

An linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$, with $dim(V)=0$, is represented by a $n \times n$ matrix $A$

So by finding the characteristic polynomial $p$ of the matrix $A$  we know by Cayley-Hamilton theorem that $p(A)=\Bbb{O}$

Then degree of the polynomial is $n$